# Is it possible to migrate an API Plugin from Shopware 5 to Shopware 6?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware5, shopware6-api

I would like to migrate an API Plugin (which we created) from Shopware 5 to Shopware 6.

Is it possible or should I have to create a new API on Shopware 6 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shopware 6 is a complete rewrite, so the code base and also the API is completely different then the shopware 5 one.

So it is best to create a complete new plugin.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So the only solution is to create a new plugin or can we go through a headless sales channel ?

Comment: Not sure what you want to accomplish in your plugin, but if you "only" want to use the API shopware 6 already provides, there is no need to create a plugin for that

Comment: Okey, what do you mean by " the API shopware 6 already provides " ? for Information, our API was created to list products on IOS and Android App, that's why we need to use this Plugin on Shopware 6

Comment: Shopware 6 is designed API first, therefore there already is an existing API to get the product list over API, so i would guess a plugin is not needed on your side to provide that API, you should adapt your apps to use API shopware 6 already provides. For the API-docs take a look here: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/concepts/api/store-api

Answer (score 1):

The APIs differ too much, so you won't be able to superficially migrate from the plugin system of Shopware 5 to the plugin system of Shopware 6. You'll have to adapt to the API of Shopware 6 entirely.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Otherwise can we go through a headless sales channel ?